Expo React Native app can't open with a dynamic route from web app
Why can't I open my react native app with the specific dynamic routes?
For example: I would like to open the app with a specific page of "/grades/1/subjects". I entered my web app inside safari and then clicked on Return to App
Here is the example code from my nextjs web app

Here is what I got in my expo app after coming back from the web app from the safari

